# How to find the probability that 2 comes before any even number in any 20! permutations possible?

Tags: probability

Suppose we uniformly and randomly select a permutation from the 20! permutations of 1, 2, 3 ... ,20. What is the probability that 2 appears at an earlier position than any other even number in the selected permutation?
Any no can be selected so probability of any number =1/20 ,but then how to consider the cases that 2 comes before any even number .

Answer (score 6):

Forget about odd #s, they don't matter here !

There are $10$ even #s, each of which has an equal probability of being first,

hence P($2$ comes before any other even #) $= \dfrac1{10}$

Answer (score 1):

We define an equivalence relation $R$ on the $20!$ permutations such that $aRb$ (where $a$ and $b$ are permutations) if $a$ can be obtained from $b$ through a permutation of all the even numbers in $b$.

The size of an equivalence class would be $10!$ as there are $10!$ ways to permute the even numbers inside a permutation. For each equivalence class, there are $9!$ ways to arrange the even numbers such that the $2$ is in front.

Hence, the total number of permutations which have 2 in front of every other even number would be: $$\text{number of equivalence classes}\times\text{number of such permutations in an equivalence class}\\=\frac{20!}{10!}\times{9!}=\frac{20!}{10}$$

As such, the probability of 2 appearing before every other even number would be $\frac{1}{10}$.